# NodeJS - Mongoose, subdoc object has no method .id() or .create()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to insert a subdocument using .create() and also query said document using .id(). I've been following the guide [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

I am getting the error: object has no method 'id()' or 'create()'

The following is my code:

*/db/schemas/AnnouncementsSchema.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    dateCreated: String,
    dateEdited: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    summary: String,
    body: String
});

var announcementsSchema= new Schema({
    categoryName: String,
    posts: [postSchema]
});

announcementsSchema.methods.Update = function (callback) {
    console.log('Updating object: ' + this);

    this.save(function (err, object) {
        callback(err, object);
    });
}

var announcements = mongoose.model('announcements', announcementsSchema);
var post = mongoose.model('post', postSchema);

module.exports = {
    announcements: announcements,
    post: post
};
```

*/routes/Announcements.js*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var announcementsSchema = require('../../db/schemas/AnnouncementsSchema.js');

exports.InsertPost = function (req, res) {

    var announcements = announcementsSchema.announcements;
    var post =  announcementsSchema.post;

    var categoryToEdit = req.body.categoryToEdit;
    var newPost = req.body.newPost;

    announcements.GetById(categoryToEdit._id, function (err, announcment) {

        var postToAdd = new post(newPost);

        announcment.posts.create(postToAdd);

        announcment.Update(function (err, object) {
            res.send({ err: err, data: object});
        });
    });

}
```

I have the .save method wrapped so I can add extra functionality if needed. I crashes when it calls .create(). The same is true if I am trying to remove a post as well. Here is the code for that:

```
exports.DeletePost = function (req, res) {

    var announcements = announcementsSchema.announcements;

    var categoryId = req.body.categoryId;
    var postId = req.body.postId;

    announcements.findById(categoryId, function (err, object) {

        var postToDelete = object.posts.id(postId);

        console.log(postToDelete);

        res.end();
    });

}
```

Either way they both crash and google is pretty slim on answers. Most people have given a of different ways to expose the schemas and models, and what I have above is pretty much a sum of what they suggested. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer after toying with this forever. It was simple. The order in which you declare your schema matters. So I had to declare my subdocument schema before I declare my parent schema. Such as:

```
var announcementsSchema= new Schema({
    categoryName: String,
    posts: [postSchema]
});

var postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    dateCreated: String,
    dateEdited: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    summary: String,
    body: String
});
```

This worked! I am now able to keep all the rest of the code the same, but now the methods exist!

Comment: Excellent! I refactored my code and it broke a really core piece of functionality (that used id()) but I couldn't figure out why. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @CMPSoares Define subdocument schema BEFORE parent schema. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I recently picked up Express.js, I will do my best in trying to provide a useful answer. Hope it helps!

If you want to access the id of a particular post, it is stored in the `._id` property, not `id`. Moreover, I believe that you first have to loop over `object.posts` since it is an array of posts:

```
exports.DeletePost = function (req, res) {

    var announcements = announcementsSchema.announcements;

    var announcementId = req.body.announcementId;
    var postId = req.body.postId; // This is the _id property of an element contained within the posts array
    var postToDelete = {};

    announcements.findById(announcementId, function (err, object) {

        // Get the posts array
        var posts = object.posts;

        // Loop over it until you find the post with the id that you stored in postId
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i ++) {
           if (posts[i]._id == postId) {
               postToDelete = posts[i];
           }
        }

        console.log(postToDelete);

        res.end();
    });

}
```

As for your InsertPost function, you should also take into account the fact that `posts` is an array. Hence, you could simply `push` the new post into that array and save it accordingly:

```
exports.InsertPost = function (req, res) {

    var announcements = announcementsSchema.announcements;
    var post =  announcementsSchema.post;

    var announcementId = req.body.announcementId; 

    var newPost = req.body.newPost;

    announcements.findById(announcementId, function (err, announcment) {

        var postToAdd = new post(newPost);

        announcment.posts.push(postToAdd);

        announcment.save(function(err) {
           if (err) {
               res.send(500, { error: err.stack });
           }

           console.log('Success');

           res.end();
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but .id and .create are special methods for finding sub docs by their id. See [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). It allows you to query without having to loop over things.